# react native input elements: change the height of input container

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have an input container using react-native-elements, and the container includes an icon. I would like to reduce the height of the container but getting a bad result, the height around the icon doesn't fit:

[image]

My styling:

```
input: {
      layout: {
        ...inputs.darkCredentials,
        containerStyle: {
          ...inputs.darkCredentials.containerStyle,
          width: '100%',
          padding: 0,
          marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 25 : 17,
          marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 15 : 13,
          borderRadius: 12,
          height: 32,
          // marginBottom: 45,
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: '#000000',
          shadowOffset: { height: 0.5 },
          shadowOpacity: 0.15,
          shadowRadius: 5,
        },
        leftIconContainerStyle: {
          ...inputs.darkCredentials.leftIconContainerStyle,
          // height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 45,
          backgroundColor: greenPrestoDark,
          padding: 0,
          height: 32,
          margin: 0,
          paddingLeft: 15,
          borderRadius: 12,
        },
        labelStyle: {
          marginLeft: 10,
          height: 32,
          color: 'white',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: -25,
        },
      },

and for the icon:

   icon: {
      layout: {
        type: 'material-community',
        name: 'lock',
        ...icons.darkCredentials,
        size: 32,
        height: 32,
        style: { color: 'white' },
      },
```

I'm trying to set height: 32 everywhere

What should I do to reduce the height of the input container altogether?

Comment: Have you tried to reduce your icon size? Try to add a size prop to your Icon component

Comment: Yes I tried thanks but it's not working even if the size of the icon itself it very small, there is still height that it takes automatically and I cannot get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Can you charge this way

```
 inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
  inputStyle: {
    height:200
  },
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying this it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This is My way

```
 <Input
            inputStyle={{
              fontSize: 12,
            }}
            // labelStyle={{height: 8}}
            inputContainerStyle={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              height: 30,
              marginLeft: pxToDp(-8),
              borderColor: '#2F4972',
              backgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
            }}
            placeholder="设备名称/位置信息"
            placeholderTextColor="#000"
          />
```

the `inputContainerStyle` is key